# fastAPI GET using a json query parameter

Tags: fastapi

With fastAPI I would like GET to accept a json query parameter.
On the server side:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import Query
from pydantic.types import Json

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/api/shows")
def get_chart(q: Json = Query()):
    return q
```

This works fine in the browser.

On the client side:

```
import requests

r = { "q": { "names": [ "John", "Patrick", "Lydia" ] } }
ans = requests.get(url = "http://171.0.0.1:8000/api/shows", params = r)
data = ans.json()
print(data)
```

I got

```
{'detail': [{'loc': ['query', 'q'], 'msg': 'Invalid JSON', 'type': 'value_error.json'}]}
```

How can I properly send this information to the server ?
Thanks

Comment: You can't send JSON-like data via a GET request. Better consider using a POST request.

Comment: Maybe you need to serialize `r` into `str` first. Though, as the comment above says, it's a bad idea to use `JSON` for a `GET` request, as `Rest` is not though to be used that way. You would be better off with a `POST` request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests

json_r_data = json.dumps({ "names": [ "John", "Patrick", "Lydia" ] })

r = { "q": json_r_data }
ans = requests.get(url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/shows", params = r)
data = ans.json()
print(data)
```

Above code works for me. By explicitly converting query param data to required data type

Note: Please adjust your host your url based on where server is running

Comment: I tried many things but not this one because the server is expecting a json variable and we pass a string encoding a json variable, but obviously fastapi interprets it correctly. Thanks !